# What's "X-KeepSent" header in email?

Tags: email, mime

We received an email with unknown header :

```
...
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Gestion_des_impay=E9s_=3A_fichiers_du_03=2F04=2F2012?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-KeepSent: 41247AD0:C9969B98-C12579D5:004A3203;
 type=4; name=$KeepSent
Message-ID: <OF41247AD0.C9969B98-ONC12579D5.004A3203-C12579D5.004A3987@bnpparibas.com>
From: ...
```

My question is what's this [X-KeepSent] header ???
This header seems to create some problems.

Comment: Any header that starts with `X-` is application specific, so application developers are free to use them for their own purposes.

Comment: I know ^^ that why I ask... Seems to me it's Lotus Note custom extention.

Comment: It seems that's I not the only one who have pbs with this header https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/79aefbf0-b2c2-42ac-870e-10ac49c73746/scsm-cannot-parse-email-sended-from-lotus-notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be [IBM Notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Notes)

Found reference about this header :

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/79aefbf0-b2c2-42ac-870e-10ac49c73746/scsm-cannot-parse-email-sended-from-lotus-notes